# Jestjs Can't Mock Nested Local Function

Tags: jestjs

I have a bit of a conundrum trying to get a *manual mock* working with some local code.  Basically there's a component that interacts with an async resource (in this case `lowdb`).  Now I could mock all the functions I'm using from `lowdb` but the output of this function is actually very simple and I'd rather just mock that call.  However, the test I'm building doesn't directly call this function.

This is probably not clear, so here is an example (this is the method that I want to mock):

```
export const getNextId = (): Promise<number> => {
   return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
      // not the actual call, but akin to it
      getDB().then((db: LowdbAsync<Schema>) => {
        resolve(db.get('count').value()) as number
    }
}
```

Then in a *different* file I use this to set the ID (this is used for some I/O).

```
import { getNextId } from '../../db'

export interface Job {
 id: number
}

export class Job implements Job {
 constructor(public id: number) { }
}

export const getNewJob = (): Promise<Job> => {
  return new Promise<Job>((resolve, reject) => {
   getNextId().then((id: number) => {
     resolve(new Job(id))
   }
  }
 }
```

As ugly as that is, that's what is needed.

So in my test file, I have a line of code that creates a new `Job`.  I can think of how to hack around this by modifying the constructor, but I'd rather do this *idiomatically*.

So far, this is the *closest* I've gotten to get it working.  This just prevents it from blowing up at runtime (the test, that is), but it doesn't actually call my *manually mocked* function.

Behold:

```
const db = jest.createMockFromModule('../../db')
  // this is ugly but i'm using TS on strict
  db['getNextId'] = (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(0)
    }
 }

 import { someUtilMethod } from '../../app/util'
 import { Job, getNewJob } from '../../app/job'

 describe('foo', () => {
   getNewJob().then((job: Job) => {
     let testVal: string = someUtilMethod(job)
     // then assert some value here
   }
 }
```

While getting jest to mock the local module does seem to make it run (no problems with `getNextId` being undefined) it never actually calls my manually mocked function.  I've tried a few approaches and this is the only way that at least gets the test to run... however that `id` value is never set and logging/debugging verifies that the *manually mocked* function is never hit.

I could easily be doing something stupid, but from all I've read this *should* work.  I've tried even basic non `Promise` base calls (this is clearly not my issue), and calling the method to obtain the ID outside of the helper method (e.g. in the test) all to no avail.  There is something I'm missing in how `jest` loads modules.

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried using `jest.createMockFromModule`. I like to use `jest.spyOn` see [jest docs' example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) which can mock specific function of a module and can be done per test (i.e. restore the function to normal with `mockRestore()`).

Btw, I also added `it` inside `describe` to make it work, and `await` for the test to resolve.

test:

```
import * as db from '../src/db';
import { Job, getNewJob } from '../src/stackoverflow2';

//  import { someUtilMethod } from '../../app/util'
const someUtilMethod = (job: Job) => JSON.stringify(job);

describe('foo', () => {
    it('bar', async () => {
        const getNextIdSpy = jest.spyOn(db, 'getNextId');

        getNextIdSpy.mockResolvedValue(5);

        await getNewJob().then((job: Job) => {
            let testVal: string = someUtilMethod(job);
            // then assert some value here
            expect(testVal).toBe('{"id":5}');
        });

        getNextIdSpy.mockRestore();
    });
});
```